# Unable to get selected value of Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get the selected value of **Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor()** but I am unable to load that. PFB the code.

```
 @Html.Label("From Descriptor")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @(
                Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.desc)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control input-md" })
                .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["data"])
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .DataTextField("TimeDescriptor")
                .Events(e => e.Select("onChangvalue"))
            )
        </div>
```

But when I try to get data in **ready()** function I am unable to get that, PFB.

```
var grid = $("#data_grid").data("desc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

**HTML:**

```
@Html.Label("From Descriptor")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @(
            Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.desc)
            .Name("ddl")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control input-md" })
            .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["data"])
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .DataTextField("TimeDescriptor")
            .Events(e => e.Select("onChangvalue"))
        )
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var ddl1 = $("#ddl").data("kendoComboBox");
alert(ddl1.value);
```

Comment: So You're just adding the Name field?

Comment: Adding the `Name` Field make it able to be accessed in javascript as I mentioned in the code.